# Run Logstalgia on Remote Global Apache Log On a WHM System

Tags: linux, apache-2.2, logging

I work for a small web development shop. We have a dedicated Linux server running WHM. For fun we want to run [Logstalgia](http://code.google.com/p/logstalgia/) on a machine in our office. We'd really like it to display information about all the traffic on our server. Logstalgia use Apache's access logs to generate its visuals, the problem I have is that by default WHM does not have an access log for all sites combined.

How can I safely configure our server to output a combined/global Apache access log in a place accessible by a non-root SSH user? I am also concerned that this file could get quite large so I think I'd also need to know how to have it automatically shed old information.

To make things more interesting I'm a programmer not a sys admin so not everything is immediately obvious to me.

Answer (score 1):

Write the Apache logs to a named_pipe ([FIFO](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Named_pipe#Named_pipes_in_Unix)), and then have Logstalgia read from the pipe.

A FIFO will remain a very small and constant size.

This can be in addition to your existing log configuration-- it doesn't need to replace anything.